# How to properly organize a CMake project with multiple subdirectories?

Tags: cmake, linker, static-libraries, build-system

I have this project structure:

[image]

and I'm trying to set CMakeList.txt files properly. My aim is simply linking the library to main.cpp. So I have these CMakeList.txt files:

library/CMakeList.txt:
[image: library/CMakeList.txt]

source/CMakeList.txt:
[image: source/CMakeList.txt]

root:
[image]

When I try to build the project, I get this error:
`ld: library not found for -lMyLib`

Where is the mistake, and how should I properly organize structure for such projects?

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Please post text as text into the question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `find_library` yet you did not use `${MyLib}` **variable**. Consult `find_library` documentation.

You used `link_directories`, yet it's local to the directory it was used in. Upper directories are unaffected.

Use an `IMPORTED` library or an `INTERFACE` library to link with `.a` file. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10550334/9072753 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/41909627/9072753 answers. If it's one library only, I think prefer `IMPORTED`. Move `target_include_directories(Source ...)` to  `library/CMakeLists.txt` and instead of `Source` add include directories to your library, it's conceptually the library include directory.

I recommend, subjective, depens: move `target_include_directories(Source..` inside `source/CMakeList.txt`. I.e. keep all `Source` related stuff inside `source/CMakeLists.txt`. And maybe add `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` to `add_subdirectory(library)`.

Use `set_target_properties` instead of `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`. Overall, prefer to solely use `*target*` specific stuff instead of `set(...)`.